# How to force `dpkg` to install dependencies

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I would like to install `.deb` file via `dpkg` in Arch Linux. This `.deb` file needs many dependencies. I don't want to install dependencies one by one manually.

How do I force `dpkg` to install all dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to have `dpkg` automatically install dependencies - it just doesn't support that. There are other tools on Debian/Ubuntu systems to do that (eg, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `gdebi`) - are any of those available for Arch? If so, you'd be better off using one of those.

Alternatively, if you have access to a Debian/Ubuntu system, you can get a list of dependencies there (using `apt-cache depends <packagename`) and then once you have them on your Arch system, use `dpkg -i <packages>` to install them in one step.